# NUMBER equivalent of Oracle in Snowflake

Tags: oracle, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

So I have this pipeline that migrates data from Oracle to Snowflake. There is one column in Oracle that has datatype `NUMBER` and I used `NUMBER(38, 18)` in Snowflake for it.

My pipeline started failing yesterday because that column in Oracle now has 21 digit numbers which `NUMBER(38, 18)` cannot handle in Snowflake. I switched to `NUMBER(38, 17)` and it worked for now.

Is there any `NUMBER` equivalent in Snowflake so that it can handle any value from Oracle? I cannot possibly change the Oracle table datatype.

Comment: [Migrating Oracle Database to Snowflake: Reference Manual](https://resources.snowflake.com/migration-guides/migrating-oracle-database-to-snowflake-reference-manual) Appendix B: CONVERTING ORACLE DATA TYPES TO SNOWFLAKE DATA TYPES "Precision and scale will need to be consistent with that of the data values being loaded."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A column defined as `NUMBER` in oracle (without scale or precision) doesn't have an equivalent in Snowflake unfortunately. It is some variable-length decimal format that isn't the same as a float.

If you are not 100% sure on what the scale / precision should be, you can try to use `FLOAT` in Snowflake but that could lead to rounding errors on big aggregations so you'll need to figure out if it is worth it or not.